# Material-UI opening a Menu disables IconButton in Table

Tags: button, menu, material-ui, xmltable

When I set the open prop to true on a Menu, it disables all the IconButtons in a Table on the same page. If the open prop is false, the IconButtons work correctly.

I get the same behavior when setting open directly to true or when setting open via a state variable.

Please advise.

```
<Menu open={true}><MenuItem>Find</MenuItem></Menu>

<Table>
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell>Type</TableCell>
      <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
      <TableCell></TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell>SOG</TableCell>
      <TableCell>mySOG</TableCell>
      <TableCell>
        <IconButton onClick={this.handleFavGo} ><ActionGo /></IconButton>
      </TableCell>
   </TableRow>
 </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Material-UI version 1.0.0-beta.13

Comment: Solved: I did not understand that a Menu is meant to "popover" the other Components and take the focus. I have solved this issue by using List inside Paper inside Grid and it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand that a Menu is meant to "popover" the other Components and take the focus. I have solved this issue by using List inside Paper inside Grid and it's working as expected.